# Simplest way to store entire file structure?

Tags: c#, directory

What would be the easiest way to retain the entire structure of a folder so that it can be accessed later to copy/delete? As of right now the following is how I'm doing it, but it doesn't retain anything inside the subdirectories, which multiple different files can share to so deleting the entire subdirectory isn't an option without at least copying the root over again.

```
      //get root directories located in mods folder

        List<string> rootDirectories = new List<string>();
        rootDirectories = Directory.GetDirectories("mods", "*").ToList();

        for (int i = 0; i < rootDirectories.Count(); i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Root Directory: " + rootDirectories[i]);
        }

        //get subdirectories from each of those root directories

        List<List<string>> subDirectories = new List<List<string>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < rootDirectories.Count(); i++)
        {
            List<string> temp = new List<string>();
            temp = Directory.GetDirectories(rootDirectories[i], "*").ToList();

            //for (int j = 0; j < temp.Count(); j++)
            //{
            //    temp[j] = Path.GetFileName(temp[j]);
            //}

            subDirectories.Add(temp);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < rootDirectories.Count(); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < subDirectories[i].Count(); j++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Sub Directory of " + rootDirectories[i] + ": " + subDirectories[i][j]);
            }
        }

        //get mod file(s) from each root folder

        List<List<string>> files = new List<List<string>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < rootDirectories.Count(); i++)
        {
            List<string> temp = new List<string>();
            temp = Directory.GetFiles(rootDirectories[i]).ToList();

            for (int k = 0; k < temp.Count(); k++)
            {
                temp[k] = Path.GetFileName(temp[k]);
            }

                files.Add(temp);
            for (int j = 0; j < temp.Count(); j++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File in " + rootDirectories[i] + ": " + temp[j]);
            }
        }

        //create new ModItem
        //add new ModItem to mods

        for (int i = 0; i < rootDirectories.Count(); i++)
        {
            try
            {
                mods.Add(new ModItem(rootDirectories[i], subDirectories[i], files[i]));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < mods.Count(); i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Check to make sure the ModItem was added: " + mods[i].getRootDirectory());
        }
```

Output

```
Root Directory: mods\Blood Overhaul
Root Directory: mods\Cleaning
Root Directory: mods\SM Overhaul
Sub Directory of mods\Blood Overhaul: mods\Blood Overhaul\Meshes
Sub Directory of mods\Blood Overhaul: mods\Blood Overhaul\Textures
Sub Directory of mods\SM Overhaul: mods\SM Overhaul\Materials
Sub Directory of mods\SM Overhaul: mods\SM Overhaul\Meshes
Sub Directory of mods\SM Overhaul: mods\SM Overhaul\Textures
File in mods\Blood Overhaul: BloodOverhaul.file
File in mods\Cleaning: Cleaning.file
File in mods\SM Overhaul: SMOverhaul.file
Check to make sure the ModItem was added: mods\Blood Overhaul
Check to make sure the ModItem was added: mods\Cleaning
Check to make sure the ModItem was added: mods\SM Overhaul
```

If I need to add any more context, let me know, this  has been bugging me for the past couple of days and I want to get it solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Recursive Method ::

```
public void CopyDirectory(DirectoryInfo dir)
{

// Copy Current directory (dir) file 
//Get inner directory list
//iterate directories and call CopyDirectory(dir); in iteration
CopyDirectory(dir);

}
```